# Profiling and std::vector part of Hot Path?

Tags: c++, vector, std, sfml

I'm trying to find the source of performance issues with my application. Using Visual Studio 2017 profiling tools I got this result:

[image]
[image]

I'm relatively new to C++ so I'm not sure what this `std::vector<bool,std::allocator<bool> >::operator[]` stuff is or if this is really the bottleneck in my program or not. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code:
https://github.com/k-vekos/GameOfLife/tree/multithread

Comment: Short advice: don't use `std::vector<bool>`. It's heavily optimised for space, not optimised for speed. Every time you call the `operator[]`, a new proxy-object is being created. Consider using something else. Even `std::vector<uint8_t>` should be faster. Just store `0`s and `1`s as `false` and `true`.

Comment: Consider what you could be caching off there, specifically `world.size()` & `world[0].size()`. I'd also look at changing `std::fmod`, lot's of seemingly unnecessary conversion.

Comment: also consider using a single vector instead of a vector of vectors, you can do the coordinate-based access yourself and will save an extra level of indirection

Comment: `std::vector<bool,std::allocator<bool> >::operator[]` is (one of) the functions you're calling when you write `world[newX][newY]`. It's the same as writing `world.operator[](newX).operator[](newY)`

Comment: @George what could I change std::fmod to?

Comment: @KyleV. `%` or some `inline` function. Though honestly after looking up the performance of `%` over `std::fmod`, I would still expect `%` to be better most of the time but it'll depend on the specific hardware being used, so maybe it's more of a micro-optimisation than I thought it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a game of life, what you do is read state to make decisions.  So sure, that is most of the time.

Your access is near random due to your std vector of std vector in virtual address space.  A single buffer, with a vector of spans, would improve memory locality significantly.

If you keep a 0 or 1 in those locations, doing `+=` instead of a branch might help.

Also vector of bool is packed bits; this makes access slower.  Vector of single bytes could be faster with your simpke algorithm.

Note that fancy games of life do zone based hashing to skip frames in large areas.

Comment: "A single buffer, with a vector of spans, would improve memory locality significantly." How would I implement something like this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @kyle look for gsl span.  `std::vector<unit8_t> data( width*height );` for storage.  `std::vector<gsl::span<unit8_t>>` for access.  A span is a pointer and a length that overrides `[]` and iteration to look a little like a container, but it owns nothing.